# Some feedback on why "How to echo random amounts of dots mixed with spaces?" was deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I noticed that this question got deleted: [How to echo random amounts of dots mixed with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483271/how-to-echo-random-amounts-of-dots-mixed-with-spaces/)

It had some good answers, and it seemed to be on topic to me.

Any reasons why it could have been deleted?

Comment: It looks like the question was deleted as a side effect of the questioner being deleted him/herself. This usually only occurs to users who try to game the system through sockpuppets/serial voting/unicorn bashing.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That is unfortunate then. I found the answers by devnull and Adrian to be interesting.

Comment: Without seeing the question, it sounds hardly like a good question. I can imagine lot's of ways to do that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi is probably right. I agree with you, so I've flagged the question asking to undelete it.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby It's not fantastic, but it's not terrible either.  It has a positive score, and several answers with a positive score.

Comment: I'd say it at least deserves a chance to get axed by the community, instead of Community ;) [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483271/how-to-echo-random-amounts-of-dots-mixed-with-spaces/)

Comment: Thank you @AndrewBarber :)

Comment: Cheers, glad this has happy ending!